# vue3 It seems that the setup function returns before the onMount function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
createApp({
    setup() {
        let price = 0
    
        onMounted() {
            // axios
            price = axios.response
        }
        return { price }
    }
}).mount('#app')
```

HTML

```
<h6 id="app" class="mb-0">{{price}}</h6>
```

The current situation is that a value of 0 is continuously output.
Looking at the order, it seems that the setup function returns before the onMounted function and has already done the rendering.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `price = ref(0)` for reactivity.

https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#basic-usage